# von Neumann sub algebras of $L^{\infty}$

Tags: measure-theory, von-neumann-algebras

I know that $L^{\infty}([0,1],\mu)$ acting on $L^{2}([0,1],\mu)$ is a von Neumann algebra. How will be the von Neumann sub algebras $L^{\infty}([0,1],\mu)$ look like?